# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (Completely broken?) in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I know, I know, I could have used a for loop, dont tell me anything about that. Please, help!

```
Private Function LoadSaved() ''//Loads saved clippings if the user wants us to
        Dim ZomgSavedClips As StringCollection
        If IsDBNull(My.Settings.SavedClips) = False Then ''//If it is null this would return a rather ugly error. Dont want that do we?
            ZomgSavedClips = My.Settings.SavedClips ''//ZomgSavedClips name was a joke, I just felt like it.
            ZomgSavedClips.Add(" ") ''//This line ought to fix the error, but doesnt
            i = 0
            While i < ZomgSavedClips.Count ''//This is where the error occurs
                ClipListings.Rows.Add(ZomgSavedClips(i))
                i = i + 1 ''//First time I wrote this function I forgot this line. Crashed mah comp. Fail.
            End While
        End If
    End Function
```

The line `While i < ZomgSavedClips.Count` is bugging, I know that the `.count` should return null but I even added a blank piece of text just to stop that. Whats up with this? Should I add actual text?

Comment: You always comment your code like that? :P

Comment: No lol, I plan on selling the source later, and I am assuming that people who would purchase it do not know too much about VB.

Comment: Especially then I suggest you restrict yourself to useful comments. I get tendencies to make stupid jokes in comments too, but it doesn't look very professional :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SavedClips is null no? If it is null it could pass the test IsDBNull beacuse the both are not the same

Comment: How can I check if it is null then?

Comment: If SavedClips is nothing Then
Else
End If

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, `My.Settings.SavedClips` is still set to `Nothing`.

Comment: Makes sense, but then the error would be on the "`.Add(" ")`" line (assuming OP left it in).

Answer (score 1):

SavedClips is regular 'ole null (nothing in VB). Include a check for "My.Settings.SavedClips is nothing". If that evaluates to true then just leave the function.

Answer (score 0):

> I even added a blank piece of text just to stop that.

All you did was *move* where the error happens.  You can't call `.Add()` on a null/Nothing object.

```
'''<summary>Loads saved clippings if the user wants us to</summary>'
Private Sub LoadSaved() ''//Loads saved clippings if the user wants us to
    ''//Load saved clips into memory
    Dim ZomgSavedClips As StringCollection = My.Settings.SavedClips
    If ZomgSavedClips Is Nothing Then ZomgSavedClips = New StringCollection()

    ''//Apply loaded clips to visible listings
    Dim i As Integer
    While i < ZomgSavedClips.Count ''
        ClipListings.Rows.Add(ZomgSavedClips(i))
        i += 1 
    End While
End Sub
```

Some notes on this code:

- Don't use `Function` when you mean `Sub`
- Since you'll be selling this code to others, you want to use xml comments at the top so that Visual Studio can give better intellisense helps.
- IsDBNull() doesn't do what you think it does.
- Yes, you should use a for loop, but since you already commented on that I left the while loop alone with the assumption that there's more code you didn't show us.

Comment: I actually meant function, I call it several times in the remaining code.

Ill use XML comments, fine, not a problem.

i was already declared in another bit of code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you don't return a value, you want 'Sub'

Comment: Alright, ill give that a shot. Could that prevent the code from working if it doesn't return a value?